# create webform from xpath expressions

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xforms

I want to build an application to edit some fields in complex xml documents. (iso19139).
The idea is to identify the fields that should be edited with xpath expressions in a configuration file and to generate the corresponding form automatically.

So, the application would extract the current values of the fields from the xml using xpath, display it in a form and put the new values when the form is submitted.

Extracting and writing the values is done by creating, modifying and writing out the DOM, but I am wondering if any of you has a good suggestion how I can automatically create the webform off the list of xpath expressions and tie the formfields to the xml fields referenced by the xpath.

There are tools to generate XForms for xml documents for which the grammar is known, but they are not a solution as the corresponding grammar is too complex.

Here is a sketch. we have a XML document containing personal info, in which we want to edit the street address and the brother. The xpath expressions in the config file identify the fields that should be editable.

configuration file: (example in xml)

```
<config>
<field>
  <xp>/person/home/street/</xp>
<name>Address</name>
</field>
<field>
 <xp>/person/family/brother/</xp>
 <name>Family (brother)</name>
</field>
</config>
```

application:

would generate a webform with a textfield for the address and the brother.

thanks
Kurt

Comment: This sounds like it might be a job for XSLT. Are you able to provide an example of the XML that you're dealing with?

Comment: @user671534: I don't understand. Do you want us to design the application?

Comment: Kurt, I think I have seen quite a few cases like this before, but I am puzzled by your comment on XForms. Would you care editing your question to give a concrete example illustrating what you are shooting for?

Comment: ok sorry for the xforms confusion. There are tools to generate webforms to edit xml documents of which the grammar is known, but of course these are not part of xforms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple version in ASP.Net...

The page would have the following controls.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="phContainer">  
</asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Save" ID="btnSave" onclick="btnSave_Click" />
```

Here is the code to build the form and then save the data back to the Xml

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    XElement xE;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        xE = XElement.Parse(@"<Fields>
                                <Field1>Field 1 Data</Field1>
                                <Field2>Field 2 Data</Field2>
                                <Field3>Field 3 Data</Field3>
                            </Fields>");

        foreach (XElement xe in xE.Elements())
        {
            Label lbl = new Label();
            lbl.Text = xe.Name.ToString();
            lbl.Width = 150;
            phContainer.Controls.Add(lbl);

            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.ID = xe.Name.ToString();
            tb.Text = xe.Value;
            phContainer.Controls.Add(tb);

            phContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
        }


    }

    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in phContainer.Controls)            
            if (c.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))
                xE.Element(((TextBox)c).ID).Value = ((TextBox)c).Text;


    }
}
```

Comment: yes, something like that would do. I would use the xpath expressions (coming from a config file) instead of the ID, but the idea is the same. I guess I wondered if there is a framework for this. ASP.net has a DataSource object that can be used with xpath, e.G

Comment: There is an XmlDataSource that you can use.  Here is an example of using it http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/XMLDataSource.aspx that you could modify to use controls in the ItemTemplate as needed.